# Conditional where clause in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables "table1" and "table2". For each row in table1, there can be multiple rows in table2. To get the data, I have created following classes

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) 
@Table(name = "table1", schema = "dbo")
public class Table1 extends BaseDomain{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer vendorId;
  private String name;
  private Integer companyId;
  private String details;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private Set<Table2> table2;

 // getter and setter for above
}
```

and

```
    @Entity
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) 
    @Table(name = "table2", schema = "dbo")
    public class Table2 extends BaseDomain{
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Integer id;
      private Integer cityId;
      private Integer companyId;
      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "vendorId")
      @JsonIgnore
      private Table1 table1;

     // getter and setter for above
    }
```

Then I have created repository like this

```
@Transactional
public interface Table1Repository  extends JpaRepository<Table1, Integer> {

  Page<Table1> findByCompanyId(Integer companyId,Pageable pageable);

}
```

This will give me the list of rows from table1 as per companyId and list of rows with corresponding vendorId in Table2.

Till now my implementation is working fine.

The response is

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "vendorId": 23,
      "name": "vendorname",
      "details": details,
      "table2": [
                 {
                  "id" :1,
                 "cityId":1,
                 },
                  "id" :2,
                  "cityId" : 3
                ]
    },
   {....}
]
}
```

Currently I am taking companyId as input and gives the above response. Now I want to take cityId as an input as well. So table2 output should contain the details of given cityId only.

So can anyone help how can I achieve it? I don't want to create another model for table1 and table2.

Comment: Before the answer, on the second entity, i think you should use `@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne`

Comment: Use CriteriaBuilder cb and create a CriteriaQuery query.where with all the three fields attached to using cb.equal.

Comment: sorry! I am new to JPA. Can you please explain more? Some sample code will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Page<Table1> findByCompanyIdAndTable2_CityId(Integer companyId, Integer cityId, Pageable pageable);
```

This method will take care of fetching by cityId. Underscore(_) refers to nested fields. But for this to work, you need to fetch Table2 eagerly.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: I also need to filter data by companyId

Comment: Thanks..Let me try this out

Comment: Your data model doesn't have companyId field ?

Comment: No but table has a column named companyId

Comment: You should have it in your data model or else Spring data cannot create a query for you with the nethod name

Comment: Yeah sorry! data model also has field companyId.

Comment: @pvkiran it worked for me. But if table2 has no data then it is not returning anything. I want to return the data of table1 in that case. One option is to provide own query in JPA  but I want to avoid it. Any Idea?

Comment: You have to write your own query. No other option.

Comment: @pvkiran Thanks man. Your answer has solved my problem. One I need one last help in this thread. What if I need to join few more tables (say table3, table4)? Do I need to write query for that?

Comment: yes, You have to . You can Just append 'And' and follow the convention of `TableN_FieldN`. Do accept the answer if it had helped.

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran :)